# segmentation fault with strcmp?

Tags: c, strcmp

I am trying to understand why my code crashes. I have an array of structs which look like this:

```
typedef struct contact {

    char cFirstName[10];
    char cLastName[10];
    char cTelphone[12];

} address ; // end type
```

In the code I initialize the array like this:

```
address myContacts[5];

for ( i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ ){
        strcpy(myContacts[i].cFirstName, "0");
        strcpy(myContacts[i].cLastName,"0");
        strcpy(myContacts[i].cTelphone,"0"); 
    }
```

This works:

```
for ( i = 0; strcmp(myContacts[i].cFirstName,"0") != 0 ; i++ ){                                             
        printf("\nmyContacts[%d].cFirstName: %s", i, \
        myContacts[i].cFirstName );
    }// end for
```

So, I only print out Contacts which have content.

However, I can't under stand why my search contact function does not work:

```
void searchContact( address * myContacts,    char * name ){
    int found = 1;
    int i = 0;

    for ( i = 1; found != 0 ;i++ ){
    found=strcmp(myContacts[i-1].cFirstName, name);

    printf(" Name Found %s",   myContacts[i-1].cFirstName);
    }
} // end of searchContacts
```

I call this function like this:

```
printf("\nEnter a name or part of a name to search:\n");
            fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer);
            getchar(); // clear the last enter
            printf("\nThe line you entered was:\n");
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            searchContact( myContacts, buffer );
```

If I search for an existing name it is found, and everything is OK. However, searching for 
a non existing name, causes a segmentation fault.
Is there an obvious thing I am missing here ?

Comment: Your initialization looks weird. Do you mean to have just a 0 byte as a start? Then you should initialize with `""` which is a 1-character string with just one `0` byte in it. A way to achieve that much easier would be to just assign `myContacts[i].cFirstName[0] = '\0';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probelm is here:

```
        for ( i = 1; found != 0 ;i++ ){
        found=strcmp(myContacts[i-1].cFirstName, name);

        printf(" Name Found %s",   myContacts[i-1].cFirstName);
        }
```

You need to add something like  `for ( i = 1; found != 0 && i < num_of_contacts ;i++ )`
otherwise you going out of your array!

Comment: Except that the loop starts from `i=1`, so the condition must be `i <= num_of_contacts`... Morale: always start with `i=0`...

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing it out. Being to used to for loops in Python :-/.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is: you cycle past the end of the array. Your loops are not bounded at all.

You should limit looping on `myContacts` to the number of values it actually holds.

Answer (score 1):

You never end the loop if search does not find any results

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in here:

```
for ( i = 1; found != 0 ;i++ ) {
    found=strcmp(myContacts[i-1].cFirstName, name);
}
```

If you don't find `name`, the loop continues beyond the end of the array. You need to add an extra test to your `for` loop to make it terminate if it reaches the end of the array without having found a match.

As it happens, I don't understand why your for loop starts at `1`. It would be more natural to do it like this:

```
for (i=0; found!=0 && i<5; i++) {
    found = strcmp(myContacts[i].cFirstName, name);
}
```

Also, your `found` variable feels poorly named. It should perhaps be called `notfound` since it is `1` when the name has not been found, but `0` when it has!